# How to interpret in and out states in scattering process for $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, quantum-information, s-matrix-theory

What can be considered as in and out states when we calculate the scattering amplitude for $\phi^4$ theory? Also, whats the role of adiabatic evolution here?

Comment: This is explained in  all the books on the subject. What bit are you not understanding here?

Comment: I do not understand the role of adiabatic evolution.

Comment: Both initial and final states asymptote to eigenstates of the free Hamiltonian, I do not understand why this is the case?

Comment: Because single-particle states are, by definition, eigenstates of the interacting theory, and asymptotically normalizable wavepackets separate from one another at late time and therefore converge, in some sense,  to eigenstates.  Chosing the appropriate sense of convergence --- the "weak operator topology" is the crucial contribution of Lehmann, Symanzik and Zimmermann (LSZ), and later Haag Ruelle and Hepp. Only matrix elements  converge, so the limit of the product of field opertors is not the product of the limits. This is the origin of the $\sqrt{Z}$ renormalization.